# Latest undetected_chromedriver Version: 3.5.1 problem

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I was using selenium 4.4.3 and undetected-chromedriver 3.1.5.post4

It was running well using the following code:

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options)
```

Now, I have upgraded selenium to the latest version 4.11.2 and undetected-chromedriver to Version: 3.5.1. If I run the same code above, I am getting the following error and undetected-chromedriver is not opening.

AttributeError: 'Patcher' object has no attribute 'user_multiprocs'. Did you mean: 'user_multi_procs'?

Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's an open thread about it here: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1441, caused by a typo in the latest version. (`undetected-chromedriver` `3.5.1`)

As I mentioned here: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1402#issuecomment-1644940051, frameworks exist with working patched versions of undetected-chromedriver, (Eg. [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) UC Mode.) For that, `pip install seleniumbase`, and then try this:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
    sb.sleep(2)
    if not sb.is_text_visible("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1"):
        sb.get_new_driver(uc=True)
        sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
        sb.sleep(2)
    sb.assert_text("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1", timeout=4)
    sb.sleep(2)
```